# How to Add a Folder to Path onn Ubuntu Virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

here is my [manage.py](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/StHRkWwyQQ/), as you see I added my software folder inside the path so that I can import any module inside it from anywhere. This completely works in my local server but when I try to deploy my django project on my real server, it gives import error every time I try to import a module from software folder. I also try add2virtualenv but it didn't work either. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: are you sure you have read-write privileges for that folders on the server?

Comment: I'll check it, however I solved the problem by copying my modules inside python packages of my virtualenv. My new problem is that django doesn't import static files even I run collectstatic

Comment: did you set DEBUG=False on your settings.py? collectstatic only works then.

Comment: yeah , I did, but it didn't work